# A common class library consumed by both .NET Core and .Net 4.5.2

Tags: .net, portable-class-library, .net-core

I'm fairly new to .Net Core, but have made a working Asp.Net Core WebAPI site - now I want to share some code with another project...

- I have Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3 installed.
- I have DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.exe installed from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows).

I would like to create a shared library (PCL) that can be consumed by two other libraries - it only contains primitive classes/interfaces with no other dependencies. One of the consuming libraries is a new vanilla project targeting "netstandard1.6", the other is an old client library which targets .Net 4.5.2 (I can upgrade this to 4.6.x if I must).

I've been round in circles, and I can't make the netstandard1.6 library reference the PCL - I just get told the types are missing:

> Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SomeTypeHere' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The PCL named "ClassLibrary1"'s project.json is auto-generated as:

```
{
  "supports": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.1": {}
  }
}
```

My consuming library project.json is:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "dependencies": {
        "ClassLibrary1": {
          "target": "project"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I make this work?

EDIT 07/07/2016:

I have made the following solution available, which demonstrates my setup:
https://github.com/JonnyWideFoot/netcore-prototype
See ExperimentClient::GetLocationAsync for where I would like to use the Contracts Library within the .Net 4.5.2 / 4.6.x Client.

Comment: FYI - they're not called PCLs anymore with the advent of .NET Core :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I have found to make this work, is to hack reference the .csproj file of the Client library:
https://github.com/JonnyWideFoot/netcore-prototype/blob/master/src/JE.API.Experiment.Client/JE.API.Experiment.Client.csproj

`<Reference Include="JE.Api.Experiment.Contract, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
 <HintPath>..\JE.Api.Experiment.Contract\bin\$(Configuration)\net452\JE.Api.Experiment.Contract.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>`

By hard-coding the path to the correct output folder from the contracts library, all is fine.

... thinking this could be a bug in visual studio.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I create shared libraries that can be consumed from both .NET Core projects and .NET 4.5 projects:

**SharedLibrary\project.json**

```
"dependencies": { },
"frameworks": {
  "net45": { },
  "netstandard1.1": {
    "dependencies": {
      "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
    }
  }
},
"version": "1.0.0"
```

A consuming (.NET Core) library in the same solution references it like this:

```
"dependencies": {
  "SharedLibrary": {
    "target": "project",
    "version": "1.0.0"
  }
},
"frameworks": {
  "netstandard1.1": { }
  }
}
```

A consuming .NET 4.5 project using `project.json` would look the same with the exception of `net45` in the frameworks section. Installing in a `csproj`-based .NET 4.5 project works too, if a NuGet package for SharedLibrary is produced.

According to the [.NET Platform Standard docs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md#mapping-the-net-platform-standard-to-platforms), simply targeting `netstandard1.1` should allow the shared library to be installed in .NET 4.5+ projects as well. I've run into strange issues with that, but it may have been the result of beta tooling.

Comment: Thanks! - Ive got the 'netstandard side' working now, but still having issues with referencing the Shared project from the .Net 4.5.2 client.

{
  "dependencies": {},
  "frameworks": {
    "net452": {}
  },
  "version": "1.0.0"
}

I reference the project in visual studio (both libraries are in the same solution), and I get "error CS0234".

However, the shared library HAS produced a .Net 4.5.2 dll. weirdly if I reference that directly, everything works.

Comment: When referencing the project rather than the DLL, the hintpath in the properties window is correct:
<src_path>\ClientLib\bin\Debug\net452\SharedLib.dll

All very Weird... How have M$ made this stuff SO complicated. .Net used to be simple :-(

Comment: @JonRea: To clarify - are you referencing the shared project from a .NET 4.5.2 project that's based on `project.json` or based on `csproj`?

Comment: "are you referencing the shared project from a .NET 4.5.2 project" - yes ... "based on project.json or based on csproj" -- it depends on which VS template I select. Ive tried with both xproj and csproj, both having a project.json.

Comment: I have edited the question to add an example solution.

Comment: @JonRea I can't see any option to create a project with the `project.json`config. Have they gone back to the `.csproj` format?